# Tar puts additional backslash in front of every backslash in bash

Tags: bash, shell, tar

I have an array `$files` which contains addresses of files I want to tar together. I do it like this: `tar czf "output.tgz" "${files[@]}"`. It all works until there are is a file with spaces in its name. For that I use `path="${path// /'\ '}"` which replaces all `<space>` with `\<space>` and after that I'll add it like this `files+=("<space>$path");` into the `$files` array.

When I try to do it with just a single test file called `main and space.c`, the `$files` is set correctly on: `/home/tom/Desktop/main\ and\ space.c` when I call `echo "Files array looks like this: $files"` just before tarring, but when the program comes to the tarring on the next line, I get the error:

> tar:  /home/tom/Desktop/main\\ and\\ space.c: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Can I make tar avoid putting the additional backslashes there?

Comment: Add output of `declare -p files` to your question (no comment).

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. The point of an array is to safely handle lists of values which themselves contain spaces. `files=("foo bar" "hello word"); tar czf "output.tgz" "${files[@]}"` should already create a gzipped tarball containing the two files `foo bar` and `hello world`.

Comment: It wasn't tar that put additional backslashes, it was you through doing `path="${path// /'\ '}"`

Comment: @chepner FML! You're right. I forgot about the additional space in front of the address I was putting there..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fighting against your array in the first place. Just add properly quoted names to the array; the shell will handle the contents of the array for you.

```
$ files=()
$ files+=("test 1.txt")
$ files+=("test 2.txt")
$ files+=("test 3.txt" "test 4.txt")
$ tar czf output.tgz "${files[@]}"
$ tar tzf output.tgz
test 1.txt
test 2.txt
test 3.txt
test 4.txt
```